# How to find that a string/integer element is in a list or not, list is entered by user?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

This is the code I entered

```
l = input("Enter a list : ")

lst = list(l)

item = int(input("Enter an element : "))
s = len(lst)

for i in range(s):
    if item == list[i]:
        print("Element is in the list")
        break
    elif item != list[i]:
        print("Element is not in the list")
        break
```

When I enter any element such as a string element it always shows element not found in the
list, Here is the code sample of the result

```
Enter a list : ["Tan", "Ban", "Ran"]
Enter an element : "Tan"
Element is not in the list
```

Comment: If you apply `list()` to a string, the *individual characters* of the string become the elements of the list.  So the elements of your input `["Tan", "Ban", "Ran"]` are `[`, `"`, `T`, and so on - nothing longer than one character will be present in the list.

Comment: To format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `in` keyword. `if item in list:`  and that should solve the problem. But that is not the only problem. `list(l)` separates every character entered. So you need to take a string as input and then split it. Correct Code:

```
l = input("Enter a list(items separated by a space) :") # Entering String
l = l.split() # converting string to List by separating elements
item = (input("Enter an element : ")) # The element won't necessarily be an integer, 
                                      # so take a string input
# Conditional Statements
if item in l: 
    print("Element is in the list")

else:
    print("Element is not in the list")
```

Sample Output:

```
Enter a list(items separated by a space) :
Tan Ban Can
Enter an element : 
Tan
Element is in the list
```